# Истиная суть объявления типов данных в MySql

Tags: mysql

Когда объявляешь id INT  это значит что MySql при заполнении автоматически будет выделять память для ячейки  в 4 байта не зависимо от веса введенных данных? Или же будет просто ограничивать ячейку в 4 байта по памяти каждый раз проверяя  не превышает ли заполненное значение этот потолок?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Да, MySQL выделит определенное кол-во памяти и оно будет постоянно, вне зависимости от того, что там храниться. В INT вы можете сохранить 1, но все равно 4 байта это займет.

Comment: ЙО МАЕ((( Кая засада то((( Очень надеюсь, что вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: Нет, я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А не могли бы вы мне ссылочку на мануальчик кинуть где это описывается или книгу по рекомендовать. 
Еще такой вопрос с объявлением типов переменных в языках то же самое происходит?

Comment: ссылка на мануал: [тырц][1]. Такая ситуация с управлением памяти имеет место в языках со строгой типизацией.

[1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html